# App Service Plan doesn't allow VNET Integration

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-app-service-plans

I just created a new App Service Plan in Azure.  I picked the "S1 Standard" pricing tier and I went to configure VNET integration since applications running in this plan will need access to a database running on a virtual network.  I had previously done this exact setup in a different subscription.

I've done VNET configurations dozens of times over the past year or two across different subscriptions.  But today, for this one, the `Setup` option for VNET integration isn't displayed:

[image: Missing VNET Integration Setup]

The link to manage existing VNET connections is displayed, but normally, when you're not yet connected to a VNET, the "Setup" option is displayed to allow you to create a connection.

Is there a limit to the number of VNET integrations you can have per subscription?  Even if there is, I've got less in this subscription that I do in the other subscription and it worked in that one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to integrate your web app and Vnet, you should do it on web app resource not app service plan.

[image]

[image]

More information about this please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#enabling-vnet-integration).

Comment: Oh man!  Yup, working too fast.  I forgot the VNET integration is at the app service level, not the app service plan.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that I had a virtual network in another slot of the same App Service.